# Why doesn't CHAR_MAX + 1 cause overflow?

Tags: c, char

There is an exercise in The C Programming Language by K&R to find the maximum/minimum values of various types, such as char and int.

In the below code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<limits.h>
void main()
{
    printf("Size of Char Max %d\n", CHAR_MAX);
    printf("Max Char+1 = %d\n",CHAR_MAX+1); //my test code 
}
```

since `CHAR_MAX` is 127, which is the maximum value of type `char`, why doesn't adding 1 to it cause an overflow?

Comment: @juanchopanza He meant since CHAR_MAX is 127, why isn't there an overflow when you add 1 to it? The 11 is a typo, I would think.

Comment: IMHO, this isn't such a bad question, just that it was written *very* incoherently, making it appear as if he was asking why 127 + 1 is 128!

Comment: Be aware that only some implementations define `char` to be a signed integer type. Others define it to be an unsigned integer type, which is far more practical.

Comment: `CHAR_MAX` and `CHAR_MIN` are not useful when working with `char` except to check the value of `int` before casting to `char`. Similarly `INT_MAX` and `INT_MIN` before casting from `float` to `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your thoughts would be correct for this:

```
printf("Max Char+1 = %d\n",(char)(CHAR_MAX+1));
```

Let's review this line of code:

- The `int` value of `CHAR_MAX+1` is equal to 0x00000080 (128)
- When converted to `char`, it is truncated to the `char` value 0x80 (-128)
- When passed to `printf`, it is extended to the `int` value 0xFFFFFF80 (-128)

Since you do not cast it to `char` in your code, the `int` value 0x00000080 is passed to `printf` "as is".

---

The answer above is under the assumption that `CHAR_BIT` is 8 and `sizeof(int)` is 4 on your platform.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I got it. And  I tried to convert 'CHAR_MAX+1' to 'char' type, overflow happened as I thought.

Comment: @zero: You're welcome. Feel free to accept the answer by clicking on the V next to it.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, whether the range of `char` is -128 to 127 or 0 to 255 or something else entirely is implementation-defined. The standard does not define if `char` is `signed` or `unsigned`, nor does it define that it has to have eight binary bits, although the latter can be safely assumed in practice today. See 3.9.1 (1) in ISO/IEC 9899:1999:

> (...) It is implementation-defined whether a `char` object can hold negative values. (...)

The only guarantee there is is that `CHAR_MIN` is no larger than 0 and `CHAR_MAX` no smaller than 127 (in Annex E).

As for the addition, you don't get an overflow because  both `CHAR_MAX` and `1` (as well as `11`) are `int`, not `char`, so no overflow can be expected.

Moreover, even the addition on

```
char c = '\x7f';

c + c;
```

(i.e., `char + char`) has type `int` and does not overflow even if `char` is `signed` because the *usual arithmetic conversions* are applied to the operands of `+`. In a nutshell, these state that in arithmetic operations, all operands are converted up to the largest involved type, and also that the *integer promotions* are applied to integral types. The integral promotions state that, where they are applied, integral types smaller than `int` are converted up to at least `int`, so again we have `int + int` and no overflow.

Addendum/side note about the "eight binary bits" remark in the first paragraph: As a matter of historical interest, the problem extends beyond the number of bits a datatype has even on binary computers. It is of little practical relevance today, but C was written at a time when not all common computers used a two's complement representation for integers. It is for this reason that the implementation limits given for signed types in Annex E are symmetric (for example, `INT_MAX <= 32767` and `INT_MIN >= -32767` instead of -32768). On machines that used one's complement or signed magnitude representation, the assymetry we're used to simply didn't exist, and there were two zero values (0 and -0).

Comment: 4 answers, and this is the first answerer who knows that `char` has implementation-defined signedness and width. I was starting to despair.

Comment: As a side-note, from those two observations follows that `char` and `int` (or `unsigned`) might have the same characteristics, so `CHAR_MAX+1` *might actually* overflow (if `signed`, meaning UB) or wrap-around (if `unsigned`).

Comment: Even `'\x7f'` has type `int` from the start. There are simply no literals of type `char` or any other narrow types in C.

Answer (score 2):

You are printing the value of `CHAR_MAX` in integer type(%d). So it will print the value as
in integer data type.

Total range of `char` is  `-128 to 127`.

For integer is four bytes. So there is no overflow.

You can try this.

```
char a=256;
```

When you are assigning like this you will get the warining.

```
warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
```

Comment: Even though he use %c it will be no overflow, because will treated as -128.

Comment: @EricWang No that is incorrect. If a + b is giving you any other result than the (mathematical) sum of a and b, there is definitely some overflow or underflow involved. Here it would cause undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

`CHAR_MAX` in  is defined as a macro constant, not of type `char` as you seem to be thinking. Take a look [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits).

In `printf("Max Char+1 = %d\n",CHAR_MAX+1);`, the preprocessor substitutes `CHAR_MAX` to `127`. Since 127 + 1 is 128, and the format specifier is `%d` (int), there is no overflow.